# AJAX Pagination how to handle new data which is updated in the background(Database)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with user data, with ajax pagination using PHP. User's name is listed in descending order(last inserted data will be shown in first page). Suppose there are 3 pages having 2 data's(user name) per page . Imagine, i visited the second page it shows some data, imagine(Alan and Arun - user names). At the same time couple of data is inserted in the database and i requested the 3rd page. But it will show the same data as previous,as a couple of data is inserted in the database. My Question is - How can i handle this. It will create a confusion to the user. Hope you get my point.

Comment: You can create some kind of ping service in JS to see if there is any new update on the server. If there is: fetch it and update in your App.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. As you said,notify the user about the updated data while he request a newer page will be a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy solution I could think of would be a timestamp, when you first requested the page. Now you keep this timestamp while navigating through the pages and only display entries older than the timestamp. This way, no new entries would pollute the result and mess with the pagination.

But you'd need to think of a mechanism to let the user include newer entries. E.g. a box display at the top saying "New entries available. Click here to refresh.". A click on this box would refresh the timestamp and navigate back to page 1.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. As you said,notify the user about the updated data while he request a newer page will be a better solution. Thus we can avoid the confusion.

Comment: How does this work? It will only reduce confusion when you tell the user what's going on, but it will not solve it, because it's still unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly it was my question. How can we manage it logically rather notifying user.

Comment: What about my solution?

Comment: Yes. I agree with the TIMESTAMP solution.

Comment: Yeah sure. Once again i appreciate for your interest and the suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some kind of ping service in JS to see if there is any new update on the server. If there is: fetch it and update in your App. Also, you can create a unique identifier to solve the problem of duplication.

Comment: But when we try to update the data in the page, it will affect the user experience, If the user was referring any data in the current page he will lost his focus.